# Using SIMD in DMD?

Tags: d, simd, dmd

I'm trying to use SIMD intrinsics with 32-bit DMD on Windows. I'm importing `core.simd` and trying to use `float4` but I get an error:

> Error: undefined identifier 'float4'

According to the [documentation](https://dlang.org/spec/simd.html) I should use some compiler flags:

> Depending on the architecture, compiler flags may be required to
>   activate support for SIMD types.

but the documentation does not state what those flags are and running `dmd --help` I didn't see anything that enables it. How do I enable SIMD on 32-bit DMD?

Comment: I'm somewhat sure simd isn't implemented on 32 bit dmd but don't have the link yet... compile with `-m64` and see if it works. If so, you can tell it is a 32 vs 64 bit difference in the compiler.